# React is not defined in simple React component ( Universal )

Tags: node.js, reactjs, isomorphic

I'm using 15.0.1 and using React to create Universal app

I was getting React is not defined in the following component

```
import {Component} from "react";

export default class HeroSearchView extends Component{

    render() {

        return (
            <div className='row'>
                hello
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The following code call that React component

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Coupon from '../../common/components/Coupon'
import { actions as miscActions } from '../../redux/modules/misc'
import HeroSearchView from './components/HeroSearchView'


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    misc:state.misc
})

export class HomeView extends React.Component{
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <HeroSearchView  />
                <Coupon {...this.props} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, Object.assign({}, miscActions))(HomeView)
```

I'm kind of scratching my head now what the following message means ...

```
ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at HeroSearchView.render (HeroSearchView.jsx:8:13)
    at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (/Users/roy/development/org/pl-core/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:679:34)
    at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponent (/Users/roy/development/org/pl-core/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:699:32)
    at [object Object].wrapper [as _renderValidatedComponent] (/Users/roy/development/org/pl-core/node_modules/react/lib/ReactPerf.js:66:21)
    at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performInitialMount (/Users/roy/development/org/pl-core/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:284:30)
    at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (/Users/roy/development/org/pl-core/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:237:21)
    at [object Object].wrapper [as mountComponent] (/Users/roy/development/org/pl-core/node_modules/react/lib/ReactPerf.js:66:21)
    at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (/Users/roy/development/org/pl-core/node_modules/react/lib/ReactReconciler.js:39:35)
    at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren (/Users/roy/development/org/pl-core/node_modules/react/lib/ReactMultiChild.js:203:44)
    at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup (/Users/roy/development/org/pl-core/node_modules/react/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js:589:32)
```

**[ Note ]** :  If I remove `<HomeSearchView />` from my example code, it works fine ...

Any tips will be appreciated ...

Answer (score 10):

You need to use

`import React from "react"`

and

`export default class HeroSearchView extends React.Component`

This is because JSX convert your file to actual JS that calls `React.createElement`, and because you only imported `Component` from react, it couldn't find references to `React`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this to keep your code tidy.

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class HeroSearchView extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <div className='row'>
                hello
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";

export default class HeroSearchView extends React.Component{

    render() {

        return (
            <div className='row'>
                hello
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Change to this and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails, then possible cause of error is that you added 
`//= require react
    //= require react_ujs
    //= require components`
 into your app/assets/javascripts/application.js